# Como forçar o tamanho de uma tabela no HTML?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela  com uma imagem de fundo e gostaria, de alguma forma, definir o tamanho desta tabela para que a imagem aparecesse completamente.

Até agora precisa conter dados na tabela, mas quando tem poucos dados ela corta e, dependendo da quantidade, ela nem mostra.  Então teria alguma forma de, independente da quantidade de dados, ela se mostrar do tamanho da imagem?

```css
table {
  page-break-inside: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after: auto
}

thead {
  display: table-header-group
}
```

```html
<table style='background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-600-400-3.jpg);'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'>
        <div style="width:100%;height:90px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tr class="linhas">
      <td style="width:50%;">Dados 1</td>
      <td style="width:50%;">Importante: aadadagdsgsagsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linhas">
      <td style="width:50%;">Dados 2</td>
      <td style="width:50%;">Importante: aadadagdsgsagsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linhas">
      <td style="width:50%;">Dados 3</td>
      <td style="width:50%;">Importante: aadadagdsgsagsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linhas">
      <td style="width:50%;">Dados 4</td>
      <td style="width:50%;">Importante: aadadagdsgsagsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="linhas">
      <td style="width:50%;">Dados 5</td>
      <td style="width:50%;">Importante: aadadagdsgsagsa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim, para isso podes usar CSS (width e height). Exemplo:

```css
table {
  background-image: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  color: #caa;
}

tr {
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Bons sonhos...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Adicionei um border para ele visualizar melhor.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti obrigado :)

Comment: @Sergio Cara olha um exemplo do codigo https://jsfiddle.net/VitorBueno/ow9jvqx1/9/  
Esta vendo que coloquei o height: 400px; mas digamos que ele seja apenas de 50 ou 100, acaba cortando a imagem que esta de fundo, quero que seja impresso do tamanho da folha de fundo, nao que a imagem se auto ajuste para caber no tamanho da tabela

Comment: Eu coloquei a imagem de background da tabela, porque as vezes os dados vão de mais de uma pagina, e assim replica a imagem para próxima pagina, e meu problema é só este, quando pula pagina e não tem dados suficientes para mostrar a imagem de fundo completa, e também quando só tem uma pagina e não tem dados suficientes para mostrar a imagem de fundo completa